# Adding Excel Reports / TFS Web Part to My Site

Tags: my-site, excel-services, tfs

I'm using Sharepoint 2013 and would like to add some Excel Reports to "My Site" but I don't know where to begin. Excel Services have been configured correctly since we also have the team foundation server web access running with excel reports on the dashboard.

I also wanted to add the TFS web part but it does not show up anywhere.